# Software that allows different profiles on phones

Tags: security, phone

I want to be able to set a mobile phone up so it logs in with different profiles based on the code entered. The different profiles would have different apps etc and would be separate from each other.

A few points

- The code would be entered when logging into the device
- If its part of a newer os which one.

This could be on any OS

Comment: Give 'er a read: https://www.silentcircle.com/products-and-solutions/devices/silent-os/#section_3

Comment: Logs in where to? What code entered where? Sounds as if Android's built-in multi-user capability matches your needs – if I understood your question correctly that you want to log in to the device itself with different credentials.